# Is it possible to open Android application automatically every x number of minutes?

Tags: android

Is it possible to open automatically our Android app to a specific screen within it every x number of minutes? Our goal is to make the application launch if the user enables this through the app's settings.

Also, does this violate any rules or guidelines?

Comment: yes, it's possible. Register alarm manager and start your activity after broadcast receiver trigerred.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

Use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set an alarm and when it occurs, start a new activity and set other alarm to the next try.

You can do it, but I don't know any application that do that, so maybe there is a reason... (I as a user, think that is horrible, but if you want...)

**Updated:** If It's an option inside the settings... why not?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following lines of code to your launcher activity (Let's say it is **MainActivity.java**). It will start itself after x number of minutes

**MainActivity.java**

```
int intervalInMinutes =  x * 60 * 1000;

Long time = Long time = System.system.currentTimeMillis() + intervalInMills;

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
```